# Замена url в скрипте?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Всем привет! Никак не получается заменить url в скрипте по клику на див. Как это реализовать? Заранее спасибо!

```
<div id="button">Кнопка</div>
```

Вот сам скрипт

```
<script>
    $('#button').click(function () {
        $.modal({
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'home/1.html'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перепиши функцию вот так

```
<script> $('#button').click(function (url) { $.modal({ type: 'ajax', url: url }); }); </script>
```

а потом при перед вызовом меняй url

С учетом последнего комментария где расписано что да как можно сделать так:
При нажатии на картинку вы меняете глобальную переменную URL. А функция обработки клика по div становится такой

`<script> $('#button').click(function () { $.modal({ type: 'ajax', url: url }); }); </script>`

- где url - и есть глобальная переменная, содержащая адрес соответствующей выбранной картинки.

Comment: Извините за мою тупость, можно чуть подробнее)

Comment: вы чужой код переделываете или свой делаете?
Я просто к чему спрашиваю - можете описать для чего это вам надо , и возможно будет найдено элегантное решение

Comment: Код не мой, задача стоит такая:
1. есть несколько картинок и одна кнопка, нужно чтобы при клике на отдельную картинку заменялся url в скрипте, чтобы нажав на кнопку загружалась определенная информация для конкретной страницы. Как то так.